# is SSDT table writable in windows7?

Tags: windows, driver

I have written a windows7 device driver which hooks SSDT entry.
I thought SSDT (Secondary System Descriptor Tables) is write protected. but I tried to overwrite SSDT anyway
and it was successful without error.
I was doing this on native machine(not in VM)
I printed CR0 register to check if WP was cleared before overwrite SSDT.
the WP bit of CR0 was set...
how could I overwrite SSDT with out any circumvention?
I don't understand how this is possible.
can someone explain this?

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT driverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {

unsigned int m_cr0=0;
__asm
  {
          push eax
          mov eax, CR0
          mov m_cr0, eax;
          pop eax
  }

DbgPrint("CR0 : %08X\n", m_cr0);
driverObject->DriverUnload = Unload_driver;
DbgPrint("Hooking API! SSDT:%08X\n", (unsigned int)((void*)&KeServiceDescriptorTable));

Hooking();

return(STATUS_SUCCESS);
```

}

```
#define SYSTEMSERVICE(_name) KeServiceDescriptorTable.ServiceTable[*(DWORD *) ((unsigned char *)_name + 1)]


void Hooking(void){

DbgPrint("Hooking API! ZwCreateFile : %08X, index : %d\n", ZwCreateFile, *(DWORD *) ((unsigned char *)ZwCreateFile + 1) );
DbgPrint("Hooking API! FakeZwCreateFile : %08X\n", FakeZwCreateFile);

DbgPrint("Hooking API! ZwQueryDirectoryFile : %08X, index : %d\n", ZwQueryDirectoryFile, *(DWORD *) ((unsigned char *)ZwQueryDirectoryFile + 1) );
DbgPrint("Hooking API! FakeZwQueryDirectoryFile : %08X\n", FakeZwQueryDirectoryFile);

DbgPrint("Hooking API! ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile : %08X, index : %d\n", ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile, *(DWORD *) ((unsigned char *)ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile + 1) );
DbgPrint("Hooking API! FakeZwQueryVolumeInformationFile : %08X\n", FakeZwQueryVolumeInformationFile);

//cli, sti - disable/enable interruptions
_asm{cli}
// hook CreateFile
OrigZwCreateFile = (ZWCREATEFILE) (SYSTEMSERVICE(ZwCreateFile));
(ZWCREATEFILE) (SYSTEMSERVICE(ZwCreateFile)) = FakeZwCreateFile;

// hook QueryDirectoryFile
OrigZwQueryDirectoryFile = (ZWQUERYDIRECTORYFILE) (SYSTEMSERVICE(ZwQueryDirectoryFile));
(ZWQUERYDIRECTORYFILE) (SYSTEMSERVICE(ZwQueryDirectoryFile)) = FakeZwQueryDirectoryFile;

// hook QueryVolumeInformationFile
OrigZwQueryVolumeInformationFile = (ZWQUERYVOLUMEINFORMATIONFILE) (SYSTEMSERVICE(ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile));
(ZWQUERYVOLUMEINFORMATIONFILE) (SYSTEMSERVICE(ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile)) = FakeZwQueryVolumeInformationFile;
_asm{sti}
```

}

This is my driver entry code and SSDT hooking code.
I just dumped CR0 register value and changed the SSDT entry for
ZwCreateFile, ZwQueryDirectoryFile, ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile

[image: Debug View]

This is the screen capture of Debug View (which shows the DbgPrint messages)
CR0 is '8001003B' which tells me the 16th bit(WP) is set.
but SSDT hook works fine. the system API for CreateFile, QueryDirectoryFile...
are changed for my own taste.

The operating system was Windows7 professional K, 32bit.
it is running on the actual machine(not in VM)

Comment: So You claim that You can write to SSDT even when WP is enabled and You get no #PF(BSOD)? Can You confirm this by some screens e.g. from  liveKD.

Comment: My understanding is that A) patching is only prevented in 64-bit operating systems and B) the BSOD is not immediate (there is some kind of watchdog thread that runs every so often).

Comment: A page-fault exception (#PF) occurs if software attempts to
write (at any privilege level) into a read-only page while write
protection is enabled which will lead to BSOD on x86 and x64 Windows. Normally SSDT is in page that is write protected, one way of writing to is disabling WP. From Vista on x64 systems there is a PatchGuard that protects vulnerable structures like SSDT, it does not prevent from writing, but it will make a bsod if it notices a change on protected structures.

Comment: I am positive that SSDT was writable even WP was set. I've added some detailed explanation. I am not sure the OS I am using is licensed. maybe the OS was modified to have writable memory page for SSDT...? but I think the possibility is low

Comment: Due to the tag SSDT referring to SQL here I removed that tag. Since I had no idea what SSDT was, I googled it then edited your question to insert what particlar YAFLA you were using.